# My visual studio code is using a lower version of the dart sdk

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

I have found out my dart sdk is not up to date and have downloaded the newest version however my visual studio code is not using the newer version but the older version. Im not sure if I should remove anything or what to change to get it updated

Comment: What platform:  Mac? Windows? Linux? And have you checked your PATH (or equivalent)? Does VSC have anything hardwired in the settings for an SDK path?

Comment: Im on Mac but im not sure where that path would be

Answer (score 0):

The Dart extension will first check if you have an SDK path defined in the `dart.sdkPath` or `dart.flutterSdkPath` settings. If not, it will try to find a Dart (or Flutter) SDK that appears in your `PATH` environment variable.

If you run the **Dart: Open Extension Log** command from the command palette, somewhere in the log it will record its search for the SDK which might help track down how it's finding the one it's using.

(I would recommend deleting the old version if you don't know it, and then if the Dart extension fails to find an SDK, it will prompt you to locate the one you want to use).